# Canvas - clip image and use composite operation "multiply" in Firefox doesn't work as in Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, clip

I am working on an app which uses `canvas`. I draw some shapes, one over another which can be filled with colours or images and overlap each other. I use `clip()` to clip images to fit shape, but when I change `globalCompositeOperation` to multiply it makes `clip()` stop working. I've created a simple example to present what my problem is.

Please try to open it in Google Chrome and in Mozilla Firefox. While in Chrome image can be clipped then set as a multiply of lower layer, in Mozilla after applying multiply, clipping stops working. Any ideas to solve this issue?

```js
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



// Create an image element
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {
  ctx.fillStyle="red"
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100)
    // Save the state, so we can undo the clipping
    ctx.save();
    
    
    // Create a shape, of some sort
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 30);
    ctx.lineTo(180, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 60);
    ctx.arcTo(180, 70, 120, 0, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 180);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 150);
    ctx.lineTo(70, 180);
    ctx.lineTo(20, 130);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 70);
    ctx.closePath();
    // Clip to the current path
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="multiply";
    
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    
    // Undo the clipping
    ctx.restore();
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/gwlPu.jpg";
```

```css
body {
    background: #CEF;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="158"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code *in the question*, not behind a link to an external site. If you could, edit your question into a runnable snippet.

Comment: What version of Firefox? Just tried on 61 for Android and worked as it should. (Don't have access to a desktop right now). The best would obviously be to report the bug to Mozilla's bugzilla, but now to workaround the issue, you could draw in two steps: on a first offscreen canvas do the clipping, then do the compositing on the main canvas using the clipped one.

Comment: Firefox v. 61.0.2 PC. I am working on workaround (had similiar idea), but I hope I can get it fixed

Answer (score 0):

This sounds [like a known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1333090) on Windows version of FireFox...
Only FF devs could have provided a real fix, but since the bug has been reported at least two years ago, I wouldn't expect it to be fixed anytime soon.

---

Now, to workaround the issue, you could draw in two steps:

- on  a first offscreen canvas do the clipping,
- then do the blending on the main canvas using the now clipped one.

This may incur a little memory overhead, but having a second canvas ready might also come handy if you do a lot of compositing/blending.

```js
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// create an off-screen copy of the context
var ctx2 = canvas.cloneNode().getContext('2d');



// Create an image element
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {
    // Do the clipping on the offscreen canvas
    ctx2.save();
    // Create a shape, of some sort
    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.moveTo(10, 10);
    ctx2.lineTo(100, 30);
    ctx2.lineTo(180, 10);
    ctx2.lineTo(200, 60);
    ctx2.arcTo(180, 70, 120, 0, 10);
    ctx2.lineTo(200, 180);
    ctx2.lineTo(100, 150);
    ctx2.lineTo(70, 180);
    ctx2.lineTo(20, 130);
    ctx2.lineTo(50, 70);
    ctx2.closePath();
    
    ctx2.clip();
    
    // draw the image
    ctx2.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx2.restore();

    // Now go back on the main canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
    // do the blending with our now clipped image
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="multiply";
    ctx.drawImage(ctx2.canvas,0,0);
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/gwlPu.jpg";
```

```css
body {
    background: #CEF;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="158"></canvas>
```

---

But for this exact case, i.e multiply blending, you can actually simply get rid of the clipping altogether on a single canvas.
Indeed, if I'm not mistaken, multiply doesn't really cares of which layer is top or bottom, the result will just be the same.
So you could simply do your compositing first, and as a final step do the blending over the composited image.

```js
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



// Create an image element
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    
    // Create a shape, of some sort
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 30);
    ctx.lineTo(180, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 60);
    ctx.arcTo(180, 70, 120, 0, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 180);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 150);
    ctx.lineTo(70, 180);
    ctx.lineTo(20, 130);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 70);
    ctx.closePath();
    // fill the current path
    ctx.fill();
    
    // draw only where our previous shape was drawn
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-atop";
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    // multiply blending should work the same in two directions
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="multiply";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/gwlPu.jpg";
```

```css
body {
    background: #CEF;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="158"></canvas>
```

---

And of course, you could very well get rid of clipping thanks to compositing **and** use a second offscreen canvas. *(Probably my personal favorite)*.

Comment: I have problem on Windows. Haven't tested on Android Firefox yet so it may be working correctly here. Code I've posted is very simple example. In my app I have a quite more complex situation so workaround probably won't be easy that's why I was looking for fix. I have one image clipped and transformed which has to multiply other clipped image so changing order won't do much. Is it possible to combine two ImageData sets? I can easly retrieve ImageData after first tranfsormation then combine it with clipped image but method putImageData() replaces whole data in canvas

Comment: @Luki if you have a more complicated set, then go with my first suggestion: two different canvases that you will merge on the only visible one using drawImage(offscreenCanvas). I'll try to write a snippet, but from my phone it's not that easy ;-) Anyway, the only ones that could have provided a real fix are FF devs, and they don't really seem to be working on it actively... Now the 2 canvases workaround is just fine. It will  avoid you the pain of saving the context's state, and will even offer better antialising than clip.